Shader to render Flow map/Directional Map
I am creating a pipeline to render all needed maps to create haircards and I am missing the directional/flow map from hairs. Basically what I need is a material to override the render in cycles that can render the direction of the hairs. I have this shader in Maya that does exactly that, but I have had not success on my own trying to replicate it in Blender.
The shader comes from this page where you can see what is the purpose of it for rendering realtime hair. Just scroll down there a bit and there are some visual examples. https://shuma.artstation.com/projects/L22Z3P

Thanks so much
